# How we can find difference in objects between two schemas of same database instance in oracle

Tags: sql, oracle

is there any query which we can use to find the objects which exist in say schema A, but not exist in schema B?

here both schemas belongs to same database instance

Comment: The question (and the two answers offered when I am writing this comment) doesn't make much sense. Two different users may have a table called "employees" but the two tables are very different - they may have different columns and rows and represent different employees. On the other hand, user B may have copied a table from schema A exactly, but renamed it. What constitutes "difference in objects"?

Answer (score 0):

```
Select object_name from dba_objects where owner = schemaA
Minus
Select object_name from dba_objects where owner = schemaB
```

Comment: If you don't have access to `dba_objects` you can try `all_objects` instead but it will limit it to the just objects the user has privileges to view

Comment: Two objects in two different schemas aren't "the same" just because they have the same name (or same name and same type).

Comment: @mathguy OP just wants to know if objects exist and maybe knows the schemas well enough to know that if they exist then the structures/properties will be the same or maybe it doesn't matter (i.e comparison of two versions of an application schema before upgrade where structures will be different but you just need an inventory comparison). So question as is does make sense depending on need.

Answer (score 0):

A bit more precise query (considering also object type) is

```
select OBJECT_TYPE, OBJECT_NAME from dba_objects where owner = 'SchemaA'
minus
select OBJECT_TYPE, OBJECT_NAME from dba_objects where owner = 'SchemaB';
```

If you ignore object type and you have table `X` in one schema and package `X` in other - you will see no difference.

Comment: Two objects in two different schemas aren't "the same" just because they have the same name (or same name and same type).

Comment: @mathguy pls re-read the Q: *...find the objects which exist in say schema A, but not exist in schema B* - this is exact what the query delivers.

Comment: Yes, and that is why in my comment to the OP I explained why the question doesn't make sense either. Do you disagree with my comments, to your answer and to the OP's question?